# Please explain this behaviour of the trivial reshape

Tags: arrays, matlab

Example data:

```
tmp = reshape(magic(4), 1, 4, 4)
```

and running `tmp(1, :, :)` I get:

```
>> tmp(1, :, :)

ans(:,:,1) =

    16     5     9     4


ans(:,:,2) =

     2    11     7    14


ans(:,:,3) =

     3    10     6    15


ans(:,:,4) =

    13     8    12     1
```

My confusion is that I am expecting the 4x4 array `magic(4)` to be displayed.  The following is confusing me:

1. The `i`-th column of `magic(4) is being displayed as a row in`tmp(:, :, i)`, so that`size(tmp(:, :, i))` returns 1 x 4.
2. If I try retrieving the first row of `magic(4)` using `tmp(:, 1, :)`, I get four individual results.

```
ans(:,:,1) =

    16


ans(:,:,2) =

     2


ans(:,:,3) =

     3


ans(:,:,4) =

    13
```

I have looked at the following diagram from the [help page on multidimensional arrays](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html), but I cannot work out why trying to get the usual column and row subsets of `magic(4)` return a row, and individual elements respectively. I would like `tmp(:, i, :)` to return the `i`-th row of `magic(4)`, and `tmp(:, :, j)` to return the `j`-th column of `magic(4)`.

[image: matlab 3d array illustration]

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it rigth, you are just misunderstanding the matlab prompt.

When you do `tmp(:,1,:)`, you do not get 4 individual results, you are getting one result of shape 1x1x4, but because Matlab cannot print in 3 dimensions, it prints each "page". You can check this by doing:

```
x=temp(:,1,:);

size(x)
% ans =
% 1     1     4
```

If you want to view it into one column, you can do something like

```
x(:)
%ans =
% 16
%  2
%  3
% 13
```